# How to catch F9 and F10 key presses in modal form

Tags: keypress, visual-foxpro

Visual FoxPro 9 modal form KeyPreview property is set to true

I tried in form keypress event

```
LPARAMETERS nKeyCode, nShiftAltCtrl

messagebox(nKeyCode)
```

but message box does not appear.
If up arrow or letter is pressed, message box appears.

How to catch F9 and F10 key presses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VFP IDE, F1, F2 and F10 have reserved behavior and can't seem to be overridden. However, if you compile the form as part of an application, it should work as expected.

EDIT: I tried that, but F10 still would just activate the menu on _SCREEN. F1 and F2 were detected, though.

As a test I made my test form a Top Level form and set SCREEN=OFF in my config.fpw. I then recompiled the program and finally F10 was detected in the KeyPress event.

So there is some kind of built-in behavior you have to work around. You may also see if ON KEY LABEL F10 can be of use.

Comment: I cannot urn _screen off since screen contains also modeless forms. I tried to add `ON KEY LABEL f9 MESSAGEBOX('F9 pressed')` and
`ON KEY LABEL f10 MESSAGEBOX('F10 pressed')` to form Init method but message boxes does not appear. Application contains system menu with F9, F10 hotkey whci are disabled if modal form is active. Maybe this menu still disables F9 and F10 keys.